# Extracting groovy jar

Tags: groovy, classpath

I have a jar file which contains some class, from that jar file I want to run a particular class suppose `A.class`.

At runtime I am adding that jar file in my code and extracting its content. From the extracted folder. After that I am creating the `GroovyClassloader` and add the extracted folder path into in classpath of groovy classloader. After that I am loading the `A.class` with the help of groovy classloader. Up to this code I working fine, but when I am trying to create the instance of `A.class` at that time code throw the class not fount exception for the other dependent class of `A.class`, i.e if `A.class` imports `B.class` than at the time of creating instance of `A.class` code throw the exception of `B` class not found. Maybe because the class loader is different.

Can any one suggest me how to solve this.

My Code is:

```
new UnZip().unZipIt(<groovy/jar/path>,</unzip/dir/path>);
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
gcl.addClasspath(<unzip/dir/path>);
Class<?> klass = gcl.loadClass("A");
klass.newInstance();
```

PS: jar file is groovy an file is extacted in java code.

Comment: you don't need to extract jar. just add jar to the classpath: `gcl.addClasspath(<groovy/jar/path>);`

Comment: I want to add the jar at run time, not as a dependency.

Comment: i understand. so just add jar to your classloader classpath. `gcl.addClasspath(<groovy/jar/path>);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to extract jar. Just add jar to the classpath: `gcl.addClasspath(<groovy/jar/path>);`

The code below adds the jar to the classloader `gcl` by url. However you can add it by filepath.

```
GroovyClassLoader gcl = new GroovyClassLoader();
gcl.addClasspath('http://central.maven.org/maven2/commons-io/commons-io/2.6/commons-io-2.6.jar');
Class<?> klass = gcl.loadClass("org.apache.commons.io.output.NullWriter");
def o = klass.newInstance();

println o.getClass()
```

Comment: my jar file contains httl template. In that httl template file I have imported some classes, now it is giving error while reading template. Can you suggest how to resolve it??

Comment: And where are those classes? In the same jar?

Comment: yes it is in the same jar. In the httl template some import statement are there. When the httl template is loaded by httl engine at that time it convert the httl to byte code, at that time it is throwing the exception for the imported classes.

Comment: so you have to use the same classloader `gcl` for your httl templates engine.

Comment: you are using quite rare template engine. i can't find javadoc for it. it's better to ask developers of this template engine how to set custom classloader for this engine. however you can try to set `gcl` as current thread context classloader before running engine: `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(gcl)`